# Search-Mailbox SearchQuery - trouble with AND and OR

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

I'm having a fair bit of trouble trying to search for some messages using `Search-Mailbox`.

```
Search-Mailbox -Identity $User `
-SearchQuery "Attachment:p* AND From:$email AND To:reception@contoso.com AND Received<`"04/02/2018`" AND Subject:(GfC* OR G4C* OR c4g* OR GfC OR G4C OR c4g)" `
 -LogOnly  -TargetMailbox "myusername" -TargetFolder "SearchAndDeleteLog" -LogLevel Full
```

However I'm getting matches to messages which don't match the SearchQuery criteria, in particular the Subject:(...).

For example, one email the matched the From and To but didn't have an attachment and had a Subject "RE: RE:"

Is there something I am missing in the KQL as it seems to me I might be getting `OR` behaviour instead of `AND`.

Comment: I haven't spent a lot of time with KQL, but you may need to bring each of those ORs at the end out into their own statements.

Comment: That might be it. I feel like I've tried every combination of operators, brackets and conditionals but obviously not that one. I'll check properly tomorrow.

Comment: So as @EBGreen suggests, you need to make the -SearchQuery statement look more like this: `-SearchQuery "Attachment:p* AND From:$email AND To:reception@contoso.com AND Received<``"04/02/2018``" AND (Subject:GfC* OR Subject:G4C* OR Subject:c4g* OR Subject:GfC OR Subject:G4C OR Subject:c4g)" 
`

Comment: Although you will need to back the double backticks single