# Exchange 2013 email search with multiple phrases

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

Is it possible to search multiple keywords and phrases using search-mailbox -searchquery like the following all at once:

(cat OR dog Or pig OR snake) <--any emails with any of those words in the body

and

(cat AND dog) <---any emails with both of those words in the body

or

(cat AND pig) <---any emails with both of those words in the body

or

(cat AND snake) <---any emails with both of those words in the body

or

(pig AND snake) <---any emails with both of those words in the body

etc...etc...

I need to search all emails containing single keywords and combined keywords sent or received since 11/01/2010 of users in certain OU's.

This is the code showing the logic but can't quite figure out the proper format to do this. Wanted to run just 1 search if possible instead of several.

```
Get-Mailbox -ResultSize unlimited -OrganizationalUnit MyOU -RecipientTypeDetails UserMailbox | search-mailbox -TargetMailbox "Search Mailbox" -TargetFolder "Search Folder" -searchquery (Joe Smith OR John Smith OR TD-17-15) OR (cat AND dog) OR (cat AND pig) OR (cat AND horse) OR (cat AND snake) OR (cat AND flower) OR (stone AND heat) OR (stone AND cold) OR (blue AND red AND pink) OR (purple AND green AND pink) AND (received>="11/1/2010" OR sent:>="11/01/2010) -LogLevel Full -LogOnly
```

Could someone help with the proper formatting to do this if it's possible? Nothing I've tried will work. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Can you also post an example of a valid search query?

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is 'yes' and your question could be considered a duplicate of this discussion.

> [Search-Mailbox SearchQuery - trouble with AND and OR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50452276/search-mailbox-searchquery-trouble-with-and-and-or)

With this answer

```
SearchQuery "Attachment:p* AND From:$email AND To:reception@contoso.com AND Received<``"04/02/2018``" AND (Subject:GfC* OR Subject:G4C* OR Subject:c4g* OR Subject:GfC OR Subject:G4C OR Subject:c4g)"
```

Other examples of your use case are in blogs all over the web.

Just search for your use case --

> '[search-mailbox using or](https://www.bing.com/search?q=search-mailbox%20using%20or&form=ANNTH1&refig=2137efa55bba4a229bd9e90c4c0f657b&sp=-1&pq=search-mailbox%20using%20or&sc=1-23&qs=n&sk=&cvid=2137efa55bba4a229bd9e90c4c0f657b)'

Example(s)

> [Using Search-Mailbox to look for items with a specific date](https://thoughtsofanidlemind.com/2014/10/17/using-search-mailbox-to-look-for-items-with-a-specific-date/)

```
Get-Mailbox –Database VIP –ResultSize Unlimited | Search-Mailbox -TargetMailbox AdminSearchMailbox -TargetFolder "Search Results" -SearchQuery {Subject:"Interesting" AND From:"Ben Andrews" AND Sent:"10/13/2014"} -LogOnly -LogLevel Full –SearchDumpster
```

Also, always edit your original question, to make things easier to follow, vs putting code in the comment section.

Comment: Ok thanks, First time using this site and my post formatted different than the way I typed it. I'll post an example in my post.